# wrong result with floating numbers

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this table with 1 records. Im trying to compute something call Puntaje, to get the Puntaje Result I have to follow the following formula:

```
Puntaje = (Infracciones * 10) / Horas
Horas = Segundos / 60 / 60
```

I wrote the following script, but I have some doubt and problem.
1) Is there another way to assign the values to @variables or another way to compute the sum?
2) Why the Puntaje result is 0.00, have to be: 0.854

Im using MS SQL Server 2012

Can someone help me to resolve this? Thank you in advance.

```
/* content of table: @Customer_Drivers

DriverId    Segundos  KM    QtyExcesos  QtyFreAce   QtyDesc Puntaje IDC
6172        717243    1782  17          0           0       0       0
*/

DECLARE @Customer_Drivers TABLE (
    DriverId INT,
    Segundos INT,
    KM INT,
    QtyExcesos INT,
    QtyFreAce INT,
    QtyDesc INT,
    Puntaje INT,
    IDC INT
);
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO @Customer_Drivers (DriverId, Segundos, KM, QtyExcesos, QtyFreAce, QtyDesc, Puntaje, IDC)
VALUES (6172, 717243, 1782, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SET NOCOUNT OFF;

DECLARE @DriverId INT = 6172;
DECLARE @Horas INT;
DECLARE @QtyExcesos INT ;
DECLARE @QtyFreAce INT ;
DECLARE @QtyDesc INT ;
DECLARE @Infracciones INT;
DECLARE @Puntaje Decimal(18,2);

SET @Horas = (SELECT Segundos FROM @Customer_Drivers WHERE DriverId = @DriverId) / 60 / 60;
SET @QtyExcesos = (SELECT QtyExcesos FROM @Customer_Drivers WHERE DriverId = @DriverId);
SET @QtyFreAce = (SELECT QtyFreAce FROM @Customer_Drivers WHERE DriverId = @DriverId);
SET @QtyDesc = (SELECT QtyDesc FROM @Customer_Drivers WHERE DriverId = @DriverId);
SET @Infracciones = (@QtyExcesos + @QtyFreAce + @QtyDesc);
SET @Puntaje = ( @Infracciones * 10) /@Horas;

PRINT @Horas
PRINT @QtyExcesos
PRINT @QtyFreAce
PRINT @QtyDesc
PRINT @Puntaje

/* OUTPUT
    199     -- @Horas
    17      -- @QtyExcesos
    0       -- @FreAce
    0       -- @QtyDesc
    0.00    -- @Puntaje must be = 0.854
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using integers in your calculation, so the result will be rounded off (or truncated) to the nearest integer. Use decimal values, or use 'cast' :

```
@Puntaje = (cast(@Infracciones as decimal(18,2)) * 10.0) / cast(@Horas as decimal(18,2))
```

Check my syntax - just typed this on without trying it

Answer (score 4):

Even though `@Puntaje` is declared as `Decimal(18,2)`, that doesn't mean your calculation will be treated as a decimal.  The problem is that `( @Infracciones * 10) / @Horas` is using all integers so this expression will result in the integer value `0`.  Then this integer `0` is converted to a decimal and stored in `@Puntaje`.

To fix this, you need to convert part of the expression to a decimal first so that the result will be a decimal:

```
SET @Puntaje = ( CAST(@Infracciones AS Decimal(18,2)) * 10) / @Horas
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use `SELECT @Horas = Segundos/3600, @QtyExcesos = QtyExcesos ...  FROM [RS_Reports].[dbo].[Customer_Drivers] WHERE DriverId = @DriverId`. This should work providing that there is one line of results.

2) Already answered by others, you have to divide by decimal to get a decimal, i.e. you'll have to convert @Horas to Decimal

Comment: Thank you very much, Tomas, this help me a lot too. I don't know how to qualify both.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learned. @variable should be some parameters light input parameter and output parameter.... Try to execute your Stored Procedure and see what you got in SQL Server Management Studio.

There should be a return value.